# Como efetuar múltiplas conexões ao banco de dados com Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, conexão, laravel-4

Tenho uma aplicação escrita no **Framework Laravel 4.2**, rodando no **PHP 5.6**, no Sistema Operacional **Windows 7**, conectada à um **banco de dados MySQL**, surgiu a necessidade de efetuar conexão adicional em outro banco de dados para obter informações específicas para essa aplicação, porém todas as tentativas de conexão que eu tentei não tiveram sucesso e retornam a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> **PDOException** could not find driver

Segue abaixo as configurações que efetuei para tentar uma conexão múltipla.

Arquivo: **database.php**

```
<?php
return array(
    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
    'default' => 'mysql',

    'connections' => array(
        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => '192.168.10.10',
            'database'  => 'sistema',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => 'root',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
        'sqlsrv' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => '192.168.10.19',
            'database' => 'ceps',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'root',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ),
    ),

    'migrations' => 'migrations',
    'redis' => array(
        'cluster' => false,
        'default' => array(
            'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'     => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ),
    ),
);
```

Arquivo: **Ceps.php**

```
<?php
class Ceps extends Eloquent {
    protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';
    protected $table = 'ceps';
}
```

Arquivo: **HomeController.php**

```
<?php
class HomeController extends BaseController {
    public function index()
    {
        $cep = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select('cep', '=', '01003000')->get();
        Log::info($cep);
        return View::make('home',['title' => 'Home','menu' => 'home']);
    }
}
```

Segui as orientações disponíveis na documentação oficial do [Laravel 4.2](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#accessing-connections), porém não tive sucesso em conectar na segunda base de dados.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel
Olha se esse link pode te ajudar.

Comment: Já tinha lido e tentado os procedimentos dessa resposta, porém também não deu certo, tentei novamente, para o caso de eu ter "perdido" algum procedimento, mas ainda assim não funcionou.

Comment: Vi que as vezes existe problema ao se conectar com o sqlsrv, faz uma conexâo apenas com este banco pra ver se o problema pode ser o drive.

Comment: Sua sugestão me auxiliou a encontrar a solução para o problema, obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mensagem de erro citada se deve à eu não ter o driver do Microsoft SQL Server instalado e configurado com o meu PHP.

Efetue o download do pacote de drivers separadamente no [website](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) da Microsoft de acordo com a versão do PHP que esta rodando, com atenção ao detalhe se a versão do PHP é **NTS** ou **TS**.

No meu caso, utilizei a versão de Drivers **3.0.1** porque minha versão do PHP é a **5.6.40**.

Após efetuar o download basta executar (com permissões de administrador) o programa para instalação, aceitar os termos de licença:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clicar em **Browse...** e definir a localização do diretório de extensões do PHP (dentro do diretório onde o PHP foi instalado), e depois clicar em **OK**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os arquivos de extensão serão descompactados dentro do diretório **ext**, agora deve-se configurar o PHP para utilizar as extensões certas editando o arquivo **php.ini** incluindo as seguintes linhas ao final do arquivo:

```
[PHP_SQLSRV_56_NTS]
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
[PHP_PDO_SQLSRV_56_NTS]
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
```

Reiniciei meu servidor Web (IIS 6.1) e minha aplicação voltou a funcionar corretamente.